# 1.546828 amd_gpio AMDI0030:00: Invalid config param 0014 while booting pc giving this error

Tags: 23.04

[ 1.546828] amd_gpio AMDI0030:00: Invalid config param 0014 this error shown up while booting and cause too much time too boot the pc anyone can help..?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) And provide us more detail.

Comment: Probably something related to the kernel. Have same problem but i don't encounter longer boot time.
Possible same problem:
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/2723
https://forum.manjaro.org/t/error-amd-gpio-amdi0030-invalid-config-param-0014/146088

Comment: 0.757937] amd_gpio AMDI0030:00: Invalid config param 0014: got the same error on Ubuntu 22.04LTS

Answer (score 0):

Ignore, it's just a false positive.
Fixed in recent kernel versions.